# Design patern for autocomputed fields and user entered values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

In a  custom made J2EE framework it use a dynamic computation concept where few fields are derived and values are computed on the go and saved to the database.

If the user modifies the field that is computed by reentering its value, that field should not be auto computed from now on.

Is there a Design pattern that can help me.

There are already domain POJO classes that are there. Please let me know if the question is too abstract.

Comment: For such a field I would introduce an additional flag field is_auto (true by default). On user's call of the setField() the is_auto is set to false. The is_auto could be used in trigger or in POJO class.

Comment: @StanislavL Yeah I have thought about that too, but dont to think that is too much overhead? besides, I will have to work through 100s of domain POJOs to make that change.

Comment: Can we do something with the annotations?

Comment: For me the real problem is to distinguish case when user sets the same value as the autocalculated one. For this we need a separate field (or we may use different tricks depending on the field's type e.g. sign, extra char etc). I don't know any "standard" ways solving such things.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just an idea

http://randomthoughtsonjavaprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/07/formula.html

You can define 2 fields in POJO class one for users value and one calculated (using @Formula annotation). If user's value is null you can use the calculated value.

```
class MyEntity {
  @Column(name="the_value")
  Integer userValue;

  @Formula("(select ...)")
  Integer calculatedValue;

  public Integer getRealValue() {
     return userValue==null ? calculatedValue : userValue;
  }
}
```

Thus when real value is set by user the calculated one is ignored. But the caolculated value is evaluated anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We need a way to distinguish whether the field has been overidden by user. A simple flag at the entity level may help;

```
class MyEntity {
  Integer userValue;
  boolean isOverridden ;

  public Integer getValue() {
     return if(isOverridden)? userValue: calculate();
  }
}
```

For case where there are multiple fields, I think you can define your own DS to hold the field value and use it to define the Enity.

```
Class MyEntityValue{
   String name;
   boolean isOveridden;
}
```